# Edit Boolean Value returns the default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I added a boolean field called `active` to my product model,it's default is set to true,but each time i try to edit it, a checked checkbox field is displayed,but after unchecking the box, it still returns error saying 'can't be blank'.below is my code

```
# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters

  index do
    column :id
    column :name
    column :price
    column :category
    column :image
    column :active
    actions
  end

  categories = Category.all

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :price
      f.input :active, as: :boolean
      f.input :category, collection: categories.to_a, include_blank: false, prompt: "Select Category"
      f.input :image, as: :file
    end
    f.actions
  end

  permit_params :name, :price, :category, :image, :active
end
```

Comment: For a boolean, you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes to avoid this kind of problems. If you really want to use checkboxes, can we see the html rendered?

Comment: changed `:boolean` to `:radio` but error is the same.

Comment: Can you edit the post with the HTML rendered?

Comment: It's from active_admin view,how do i get the html?